# java.io.InputStream#available() method equivalent in nio package

Tags: java, java-7, nio, filechannel

The class `FileInputStream` has a method `available()` that returns the remainging size to be consumed

I'm trying to convert a program that uses `FileInputStream` to use `FileChannel`, I konw that we can consume the `FileChannel` using a `ByteBuffer`, but what I'm wondering is how would I get the remaining bytes to be consummed from the `FileChannel`, is there any idea ?

Comment: Why? It is 1000 to 1 that the original code shouldn't have been using `available()` in the first place. There are few correct uses of `availavle()`, and I can't think of any in conjunction with `FileInputStream`. Have a good look at the documentation and ask yourself whether it is really being used correctly. If you show us how it is being used we can show you how it should have been done.

Comment: @user207421 the original code , there is a thread that uses the `available()` to calculate how much of the file was consumed , "a sort of a progress bar"

Comment: Well that's invalid. `available()` tells you how much data is available to be read without blocking. See the Javadoc. If you just want to know where you are in the file you just have to add up all your read counts.

Comment: okay @user207421 , I see , `available()` wasn't used as it should be. so to know how much bytes were consumed in order to do that progress bar, is adding the read counts is the only solution ?

Comment: It's the only solution with `FileInputStream`. `FileChannel.position()` is what you need if you switch to NIO. I think `RandomAccessFile` has that too but don't quote me.

Answer (score 0):

> The class `FileInputStream` has a method available() that returns the remainging size to be consumed

This is not a correct interpretation. `available()` returns an estimation of the number of bytes that can be read/skipped without the stream blocking. Typically, this is the number of bytes currently buffered by the stream, if any. It does not depict the number of bytes until end-of-stream.

> what I'm wondering is how would I get the remaining bytes to be consummed from the `FileChannel`

Compare `FileChannel.position()` to `FileChannel.size()` to see how many bytes remain.